# XMLHttpRequest "loaded" and "total" values are same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing Progress bar for file uploading using below code . I am getting 100% every time when upload the file also the xhr.loaded and xhr.total values are same.

```
function transmitMessage(stream,filename,askForReload){
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress');
var display = document.getElementById('display');

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){ 
  if (evt.lengthComputable){

console.log('evt.loaded---->'+evt.loaded);
console.log('evt.total---->'+evt.total);

var percentComplete = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
 console.log('Upload:'  +percentComplete  '% complete'); 
 display.innerText = Math.floor((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100) '%'; 
 progressBar.value = evt.loaded;

}};

xhr.open('POST','###SERVLET_URL###',true);xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){evalTransmitMessageResult(xhr,filename,askForReload)};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(stream))};
```

I am getting below information in the logs

evt.loaded---->66
evt.total---->66
Upload:100% complete

evt.loaded---->26239
evt.total---->26239
Upload:100% complete

Question : What was wrong with my coding why i am getting evt.loaded & evt.total same values?

Comment: Java and javascript are different languages. Please remove the java tag

Comment: Please clearly state what your actual question is, also.

Comment: Question :  why i am getting evt.loaded & evt.total same values? what i am missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried uploading a file with size 5MB or more? Is the same behavior observed?

Comment: I tried big  files too but it is having same behavior it showing loaded and total values same .